# Fix IE7 div overflow-y: scroll from hiding contents behind the scrollbar

Tags: css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, vertical-scrolling

Per the jsfildde below, I have a table inside a div(`#body`) that scrolls along the y-axis. My problem is that in IE, the scrollbar hides part of the last table cell behind it, subsequently shifting the layout of the table columns. There is no such problem in Chome and I must support both browsers. I believe that the problem is with IE and that Chrome is rendering the CSS properly. How can I make IE display my columns in the same way as Chrome?

If the fiddle is viewed in both browsers, the difference will be seen in that the table header  does not line up with the corresponding columns.

http://jsfiddle.net/5DD5b/3/

Thanks for any suggestions given.

EDIT: It works in IE9, but not in 7 which needs supported.

Comment: Strange... they both look the same for me when I load them in each browser. Here's what it looks like for me: http://awesomescreenshot.com/09fcjxv11

Is that what you see?

Comment: @ihake That's what it looks like in Chrome. But in IE7 the table is shifted over about 7 or 8 pixels. I bet you were using IE8 or 9.

Comment: AH. Oopsies. I read your question and thought the problem was in IE9. I don’t have IE7, but I can try to take a look later. The only thing I can think to do off the bat is shift the row of divs at the top and the table so that the whole row (and table) have a margin or padding of about 20px on the right. It wouldn’t look quite as good in Chrome since there would be a little unused space on the right, but then you could at least see everything in IE7...

Comment: I can’t think of any way to fix it so that it takes up the whole amount in both unless you used jQuery to check the browser version on document ready and then changed the CSS accordingly. It’s a little hacky, but it might be the only way to do it… unless there’s some way in CSS to only apply styles to certain versions of browsers (which there might be.)

Comment: @ihake I didn't really want to, but that's what I've implemented in the mean time. I'll provide my simple solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this problem only seems to occur in IE7, I decided to detect the userAgent per ihake's suggestion and proceed accordingly. It's not ideal, but it works.

```
var IE7 = false;

$(document).ready(function(){

    if($.browser.msie) {
        var userAgent = $.browser.version;
        if(userAgent.substring(0,userAgent.indexOf('.')) == 7) IE7 = true;
    }

    ...
```

Farther down in the file I set the css one way if IE7 is true and another way if it is false. Pretty simple.